# Cannot link System lib to vendor lib

Tags: android, c, android-source

- I have two libs, one is compiled under /system/lib and the other is compiled under /vendor/lib.
- I cannot change the location of one of the two libs because they are depending on other vendor/system libs.
- When i try to use the vendor lib in my system lib using : LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES, i got this error: (native:platform) can not link against lib_connect (native:vendor)"
- Both lib are developped in C code.
- I am working with Android AOSP 12 (Android S), is there any way to link the vendor lib function with my system one ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to Project Treble system and vendor libraries need to be separated since the system layer is designed to be completely upgradeable while leaving vendor untouched. To ensure a working device after such an upgrade the libraries must not be interdependent.

Thus you will need system/lib to contain all the libraries and dependencies it needs to function independently as if vendor/lib didn't even exist and vice-versa.

Take a look at tinyalsa for an example, notice the following:

```
cc_library {
    name: "libtinyalsa",
    vendor_available: true,
    product_available: true,
```

Notice how it is vendor_available so that libraries and binaries on the vendor image will be able to use it because a copy of the library will be placed there.

Read https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/vndk and especially https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/vndk/enabling#build-system-libraries for more information.

Comment: there anyway to use this : im actually working with HIDL solution and i dont know if it will help me or not. Any ideas please ?

Comment: I updated the answer, definitely recommend reading android source doc pages for details.